# Reversing the display of mysql_fetch_array on html page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a discussion type page, where users can enter their replies on different subjects. For this, I have a table name **replies** with fields **replyID, topicID, userID, replybody, time**

On the page, where I display the result, I use this php command:

```
$run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE topicID = $topicnumber ORDER BY time DESC Limit 5");

while($data= mysql_fetch_array($run)){
// do formatting and display data 
}
```

as you can see, the page initially displays only 5 replies on a topic (after which, if interested, user clicks to visit the page where all replies are displayed).

the thing is, the above code displays correctly the recent 5 replies, but I want to change the order of its display. It shows the recent most reply on top, and older replies are displayed as we go down, but I want to change this order, showing the recent most reply on bottom.

I think I'm missing a very simple point here, since most of the website have this feature where recent most comments go down, but hey, "no question is small".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested query to reverse the order in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM replies WHERE topicID = $topicnumber ORDER BY time DESC Limit 5
) AS a
ORDER BY time ASC
```

The inner query will return your most recent 5 records, while the outer query will reverse the sort order of those 5.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, You saved the Day! :)

Comment: here is another one, how can I use **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** within this query, if I also want to get the total number of replies made on that topic?

Comment: not sure if you can. you'd have to use it on the inner query, but the outer query will be the last one executed, and it won't have a limit, so the found_rows would be 0. e.g you'd have to run the query twice. once for the actual results, and once to calculate the total rows. at least if you do `select count(*) ...` it'll be relatively fast since it won't be retrieving row-level data

Comment: yes, I did the same. SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS returns only the limit the inner query generated, so returned to SELECT COUNT

Comment: 'course, since you're only fetching 5 rows of data in the inner query, you'd be better off fetching into a php array and displaying that in reverse order. that'd save you the second query to get the count().

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's very easy in sql.

I would just load the results in an array and use [`array_reverse()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to reverse the order. Then you can loop through the array and display the values like you do now.

Otherwise I think you need to do 2 queries, one to get the total amount and then one to limit your result set to the last `x` items.